# How to root a Galaxy SM-930U

Tags: rooting

I've found varying amounts of information about this subject and I'm hoping that someone here can point me in the right direction.
I've never rooted a phone before and would like to know the correct procedure so I don't end up with a paperweight.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did you check dedicated threads on XDA?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to post comments.

Would you check this thead on [XDA Developpers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s7/how-to/root-sm-g930u-tinysu-t3667800)? The method uses TinySU an lternative for Chainfire's SuperSU or SuperUser or  MagiskSU.